# Как использовать данные пользователя в модели

Tags: php, laravel

Суть задачи заключается в разбиении доступа всей БД. У каждого пользователя(условно users) есть только свои(условно posts), и я хотел выдавать Посты только к привязанным за ними пользователям

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class BlogPost extends Model
{
    static function users_doc(){
        return static::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    }
}
```

Хотел использовать такой синтаксис, но получаю ошибку Error
Class 'App\Models\Auth' not found.
На англоязычном форуме прочитал, что Auth нельзя использовать вообще в моделях.
Может проблема в Именах, но ее исправить мне тоже не удалось.

Прошу помочь мне с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете определить связь между моделями.

***Пример:***

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    public function blog_posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(BlogPost::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class BlogPost extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

```php
$user->blog_posts;
```

Comment: Запомню и этот метод. Хотел бы еще задать Вам вопрос, какую книгу\документацию\форум\видеоурок Вы бы посоветовали для подробного изучения данного фреймворка.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x

Comment: @ali Есть официальная документация: https://laravel.com/docs/. Вряд ли Вы будете читать её полностью. Но Вы можете прочитать введение, а затем отдельные разделе по мере надобности

Comment: @nomnomus
Благодарю

Comment: docs.rularavel.com - документация на русском :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать это в контроллере, который отвечает за вывод записей блога.

***Пример:***

```php
class BlogPostController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $blog_posts = BlogPost::where('user_id', request()->user()->id)->get()
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь! Очень благодарен! 
Все работает корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не использовать логику и объект auth() в модели, выделите для этого сервис или репозиторий, который отвечает за отправку данных, в конструкторе контроллера создайте экземпляр сервиса через контейнер DI и прокинте уже там юзера в сервис

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]